# JavaScript Object properties do not get subtracted

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to create JavaScript objects which contain different attributes for characters in-game that are affected by an event happening in the game's current turn. When I access the current character in turn from an array of characters and apply the changes to his attributes according to the event's effect I just can't get the attributes to subtract. Even if the properties are negative they keep increasing instead of decreasing the character's attributes. If anyone can help me understand why this is happening I would be really grateful!

This is how the character object looks like:

```
let russian = {
    happiness: 7,
    vitality: 7,
    satiation: 7,
    log: [],
    portrait: 'russian'
};
```

And this is the event object:

```
let playerInTurn = currentPlayer;
let event = {
    updateHappiness: -Math.abs(1),
    updateVitality: Math.abs(2),
    updateSatiation: -Math.abs(1),
    name: 'Cardio marathon',
    description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.',
    updateAttributes: function() {
        if (this.updateHappiness > 0) {
            charactersArray[currentPlayer].happiness += this.updateHappiness;
        } else {
            charactersArray[currentPlayer].happiness -= this.updateHappiness;
        }
        if (this.updateVitality > 0) {
            charactersArray[currentPlayer].vitality += this.updateVitality;
        } else {
            charactersArray[currentPlayer].vitality -= this.updateVitality;
        }
        if (this.updateSatiation > 0) {
            charactersArray[currentPlayer].satiation += this.updateSatiation;
        } else {
            charactersArray[currentPlayer].satiation -= this.updateSatiation;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are subtracting negative numbers.

Comment: oh lmao I cant believe i did not notice that. Thank you XD

Comment: It should be += in both cases. -= is negating it

Comment: then you need no check.

Comment: I see, It works now. Thank you for helping me notice my dummy mistake. Maybe i was too tired XD. How do I make the comment an answer to the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not notice I was subtracting negative numbers so I was instructed to get rid of the checks and just leave it at adding the attributes from the event to the character and now it works as intended. Thank you Nina Scholz, Mark_M and Slai